# Write-Host and function return value

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that execute this:

```
$result = powershell -command $((Get-ChildItem $script).Fullname) $arguments

$result | % { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_ }
```

In the script launched, I'd like to display some text on the screen AND return a value. Basically, my idea is "if something is returned => there is an issue and I display it". But I would also like to display some output because the launched script could take some time to execute and I'd like to display some output.

For now, the launched script is something like this:

```
Param(...)

Write-Host "Some status..."

if (SOMETHING_IN_ERROR)
{
  return "There is an error";
}
```

It's working except that "output messages" and "errors" are display once the launched script is done, not during its execution. I kind of understand why, but I cannot find a good way to be able to return error and display some output messages.

Answer (score 1):

Use the call operator (`&`):

```
$result = & $script $arguments

$result | % { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_ }
```

Running the script in another PowerShell process will merge that process' host output with its success output stream (vulgo STDOUT), so you're getting the whole output when processing `$result`. The call operator runs the script in the same environment, so you get host output while the called script is running, and the success output when processing `$result`.

Comment: The thing is that I really want a new Powershell session to be created. Indeed, I'm working with SharePoint and the Powershell cache is causing me some issue. (Powershell keeps referencing old file content after them being updated by SharePoint commandlet)

Comment: You can have one or the other, not both.